# SQL Parameter Name Picking Up a Different Value Than What is Assigned

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that was recently updated to accept more parameters. On one of the parameters I mistakenly assigned the wrong parameter name

```
x.SqlParameterName = "FOO";
```

So it was giving me an error saying

> FOO is not a parameter in stored procedure.

What I did was assigned the correct parameter name:

```
x.SqlParamterName = "BLAH";
```

But upon running the application, it was still giving me the same error saying

> FOO is not a parameter of stored procedure

Why is this happening?

Comment: It will be useful to see the code that creates and uses these parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns I out it was a simple yet very common case of deleting the contents of the project's bin folder that solved the issue. Cleaning and Rebuilding the solution wasn't properly updating the bin files.